# Mocked object returning null object instead of List

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Using Moq, I have a mocked object that is supposed to return a `List<>` from a function call. The object that is returned is `null` and I am not sure why.

Here I create the mocked object and setup the function to return a `List`

```
var mockParser = new Mock<ISalesParser>() { CallBase = false };
        mockParser.Setup(m => m.Parse(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new List<ImportedData>{ new ImportedData{ ReportingPeriod = DateTime.Now } });
```

It the function under test, I call `Parse()` and capture the object returned. When I try to get the `Count` of the list, it throws a `System.ArgumentNullExcpetion : Value cannot be null` exception.

I'm pretty new to mocking and Moq, is there something i'm missing?

Test Method:

```
[Test]
    public void Test_ImportNormalExecution()
    {
        var importedData = new Mock<List<ImportedData>>(MockBehavior.Strict) { CallBase = false };
        importedData.SetupAllProperties();
        importedData.As<IEnumerable<ImportedData>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(importedList.GetEnumerator());

        var mockParser = new Mock<ISalesParser>() { CallBase = false };
        mockParser.Setup(m => m.Parse(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(new List<ImportedData>{ new ImportedData{ ReportingPeriod = DateTime.Now } });
        mockParser.Setup(m => m.Parse(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => parseFuncCall++);

        var mockContext = new Mock<ApplicationDbContext>() { CallBase = true };
        mockContext.As<IUnitOfWork>().CallBase = false;
        mockContext.Setup(m => m.ImportedData.Add(It.IsAny<ImportedData>())).Callback(() => addImportDataCall++);

        unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(mockContext.Object);
        dataRepository = new ImportedDataRepository(mockContext.Object);
        parser = mockParser.Object;

        service = new SalesService(parser, dataRepository, unitOfWork);
        string status = "Parsed input file.  Processed imported data into sales history.";
        SalesImportResults results = ((ISalesService)service).Import(AmazonHtmlSalesParserResources.AmazonHtmlDataValid);

        Assert.AreEqual(1, results.Count);
        Assert.That(parseFuncCall == 1);
        Assert.That(addImportDataCall == 1);
        Assert.That(String.Compare(status, results.Status) == 0);

    }
```

Method under test

```
public SalesImportResults ISalesService.Import(string data)
    {
        var salesImportResults = new SalesImportResults();

        try
        {
            IEnumerable<ImportedData> sales = _salesParser.Parse(data);

            salesImportResults.Count = sales.Count();
            salesImportResults.Date = sales.FirstOrDefault().ReportingPeriod;
            salesImportResults.Status = "Parsed input file.";

            foreach (ImportedData salesItem in sales)
            {
                _importedDatarepository.Add(salesItem);
            }
            _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();

            salesImportResults.Status += " Inserted data into import table.";

            _importedDatarepository.ProcessImportedData();

            salesImportResults.Status += " Processed imported data into sales history.";

            return salesImportResults;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException(salesImportResults.Status + " - but then something went wrong: " + ex.Message, ex);
        }

    }
```

The exception gets thrown on the line `salesImportResults.Count = sales.Count();`

```
public interface ISalesParser
{
    IEnumerable<ImportedData> Parse(string data);
}
```

Comment: Could you include the rest of your test code?

Comment: It is not obvious from the info you gave. Please provide the stack trace of the exception and the method under test and also all depending code that the called method might invoke down the call stack.

Comment: Added the test function and the function under test.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov yes, `ISalesParser` is `public`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call

```
mockParser.Setup(m => m.Parse(It.IsAny<string>())).Callback(() => parseFuncCall++);
```

previously configured return value is reset, so it's null again. If you need to setup a return value and a callback, you can chain `Returns` and `Callback` methods together:

```
var mockParser = new Mock<ISalesParser>() { CallBase = false };
mockParser.Setup(m => m.Parse(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(new List<ImportedData>{ new ImportedData{ ReportingPeriod = DateTime.Now } })
    .Callback(() => parseFuncCall++);
```

Comment: @DFord On a side note the "proper" way to do what you are attempting to do with the callback is to get rid of your callback and replace your `Assert.That(parseFuncCall == 1);` with `mockParser.Verify(m => m.Parse(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Once);`. Also if you just want to check that your function was called "one or more times" just do `.Verifiable()` instead of callback then at the end just call `mockParser.Verify();` and it will check that all methods marked `.Verifiable()` where called at least once.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks for the tip. I need to explore Moq more and learn the 'proper' way to use it.